# how to update app icon for my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, application-icon

We have an updated version of our app icon to replace the existing one, we tried to simply overwrite the old one (image file) with the new version (image file), build and then deploy, what we found on the device is still the old icon being used for our app. Is this a normal behavior, what's the "official" steps for such needs? Note that we are still in development stage, which is why we need to update our app icons based on the new art work done by our designers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all delete the icon.png then select the image you want to create the icon select and drag it and put the following place and clean up your project(Cmd + shift + k).

[image]

Now the run the project and it change the icon of the application.

i think it's helpful for you

Answer (score 2):

Even i faced the same issue ,& its just because the app still has the reference to the old icon file or may be it has not been deleted from the resources, you may have opted for reference only while deleting the app icon.

It's simple ,

For easy followup I have attached the Screenshots too : ;)

1) Delete your application icon.png from the app, selecting an option "**Also Move to Trash**" .

[image]

2) Now **Clean build** & **all the targets**.

[image]

3) **Reveal in finder** the resource folder in your app & **first copy your New App icon** over there.

[image]

4) Now, drag & drop the new application icon from application finder to your **Resource folder**, make sure to **check the option to copy items**.

[image]

5) Also, prior to submitting the application to AppStore, make sure to do changes in your ***.plist file***.Add value icon.png value to Icon file key.

[image]

Once, you are done with all the steps, just reset your Simulator & Run the app. I am sure that would solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for the detailed steps, although neon's answer helped fix the problem, your help is still very appreciated

Answer (score 1):

do cmd+k (to clean) then cmd+r (to run)

Answer (score 0):

Clean build folder first before you redeploy, Xcode cache some of the data. To clean build folder, Go to Products, and hold option, there will be an option to.

Answer (score 0):

[Reference Apple Technical docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html), about **Troubleshooting** section. That technical document gives details about this icon issue.

The following is what I encounter.

> Error: Invalid Image Path
>
> Your application's information property list references one or more icon images that were not included in the compiled bundle.
>
> If your application is using asset catalogs to manage its icons then the information property list should not include any icon related keys; they will be added at build time by the asset catalog compiler.
>
> > Open the information property list for your app's target. It can be found under the Info tab in the project editor or in the File Navigator where it will be named either -Info.plist or Info.plist, where  is the name of your app.
> >
> > Remove the following keys, including device specific variations.
> >
> > > 1. “Icon file” (CFBundleIconFile)
> > > 2. “Icon files” (CFBundleIconFiles)
> > > 3. CFBundleIcons

---

My project use `App Icons Source` to manage app icons, but the `Info.plist` also contains `Icon files`, and images in the resources.

---

### More ...

If you encounter following case, reference [that apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html), it will help you.

> The wrong icon appears in the App Store
>   Your application bundle includes additional images which are being detected as valid icon images.